# Push to gitlab using php or laravel

Tags: php, laravel, gitlab

I have some html and css codes saved in my database. Is it possible that every time I save the codes in my database, I also want my Gitlab repository to be updated? The codes in my database is already pushed in my Gitlab repository. Is there any API for this? I will only push the codes in my database not the project itself.

My repository is like:

```
My Projects
   project 1
   ---index.html
   ---style.css
   ---script.js
   project 2
   ---index.html
   ---style.css
   ---script.js
```

Hope you can help me. Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by saving your code in database ? :/

Comment: I have some html, css and js codes (loading library for example) saved in my database. They are the codes I want to push in my gitlab repository and not my project itself @fahim152

Comment: okay. you can use .gitignore file to omit the files/directory from your git tracker. so when you push the code. it will not update your full repo. see https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: I mean using PHP. In the backend of my project, I have the codes in the database. Before saving I want, hopefully if possible, to also be pushed in my gitlab repository.